Dropdown filter does not filter the value or if it filters showing the object instead of value
I am using primeng version 16.9.1, and using the dropdown component in our project.
As mentioned in document, we should use the [filter]="true" property. If we use this property, throwing the following error option.toLowerCase is not a function. Resolve this issue we must include the filterBy and optionLabel properties, but if I add those properties instead of the selecting the value it is selecting the object (key value) pair.
How to use the [filter] along with selecting only the value
I added the code  here

You have to  use optionValue to make it populated only the 'value' field.
<p-dropdown
    [options]="cities"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
    [showClear]="true"
    [filter]="true"
    filterBy="label"
    optionLabel="label"
    optionValue="value"
    placeholder="Select a City"
  ></p-dropdown>

Stackblitz Demo
